# Is it Lac or Lakh?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spelling, indian-english

I am much confused to use whether '**Lac**' or '**Lakh**', So which word is correct to use? (In terms of money)

Comment: I added a tag 'Indian English' to keep this question in a proper category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your confusion.

At least in India, ***both*** are in practice. However, if you typically go by its Hindi origin 'लाख', the spelling **'Lakh'** is proper.

It's worth noting that [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lakh?q=lakh) has an entry for 'Lakh' and *not* 'Lac'.

[Personally, I prefer/practice 'Lakh'].

Comment: Is the "h" pronounced in any way?  What words does it rhyme with?

Comment: As someone who has had very limited exposure to Indian English, but is familiar with the word, _lakh_ is the only version I've ever seen, too. I only know _lac_ as either an Alpine glacial lake or something you use in making varnish (as in _shellac_). @Jasper Hindi distinguishes aspirated and unaspirated consonants, and _lakh_ has an aspirated k (like an initial k in English). If you exaggerate the k, it rhymes with a non-rhotic pronunciation of _park_, more or less.

Comment: no, @Jasper you literally pronounce it as in Burj Khalifa (kh). And I'm afraid, there's no 'kh' word in English.

Comment: @MaulikV When initial in a stressed syllable, regular /k/ is quite heavily aspirated in (non-Indian) English, sounding like [kh]. So the /kh/ in _lakh_ in Hindi is basically pronounced the same as the /k/ (spelt as |kh|) in _khaki_ in English. But the second /k/ in _khaki_ (spelt as |k|) is pronounced differently, like a regular /k/ in Hindi.

Answer (score 1):

Though both spellings are in use, Lac also means  a resinous material.Preferably we should spell it as Lakh which has no other meaning.